# Disable javascript of an iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have got this iframe and a youtube video as a sourcce. But it doesnt load:

```
document.getElementById("blank").style.display="block";

<div id="blank" style="display:none; position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px; width:600px; height:400px;">
                <iframe title="YouTube video player" type="text/html"  width="240px" height="349px" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGNIYEYWxm0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

I try to disable the javascript inside... The I frame, should be seen,, but I dont want it to be viewed or triggered by the user

Comment: Try loading with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: how do I do that?!? why to disable javascript..

Comment: How do I disable javascript inside an iframe?!?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested, but I'd imagine YouTube's web servers are probably sending an X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY header, which expressly forbids your browser from displaying their content in an iframe. There's nothing you can do about this, though if you want to put YouTube videos in an iframe, you probably want to read this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 0):

You can't view the page because it's disabled by YouTube in the header ( `X-Frame-Options` ).

If you would like to include this YouTube Video in your page you should use this code (provided by youtube):

```
<object style="height: 390px; width: 640px"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/F8V9Wbk_a1s?version=3&feature=player_detailpage"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/F8V9Wbk_a1s?version=3&feature=player_detailpage" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="360"></object>
```

To your second question:

JavaScript will be stopped when you throw an error but you can't access an iframe from another origin with JavaScript.

Comment: cant I put a div on it like in my answer.. But when I do that I dont see the page (The I frame)

Comment: The div is not required, the problem is that the src from your iframe is wrong, if you really want to display the video in an iframe you should use this src: http://www.youtube.com/embed/bGNIYEYWxm0